# HTML: insert line-break in email subject like %20 is a space?

Tags: html, email

`<a href="mailto:office@something.com?subject=Whatever%20this%20is &body=HowcanIaddLine<br/>Break here`

I wonder if it is possible to write something like `%20` (which stands for a space) for a line-break as well. So I want to have separate lines in my body of the e-mail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `%0A`. That's the ASCII code for a newline.

Comment: However, I don't think it's possible to add linebreaks to a mail subject

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a line break in mailto body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765834/insert-a-line-break-in-mailto-body)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should use a carriage return `%0D` and line feed `%0A`

```
<a href="mailto:endpointadress@something.com?cc=endpointadress2@something.com&subject=your subject&body=Text before new line.%0D%0AText after new line.">create email</a>
```

This is defined in [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) and is the only valid method of generating a line-break.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for gmail.com and its mobile app. Is there anything special that needs to be done for gmail to make the line break work?

Comment: @JasonO. in gmail for Android you can use my answer

Comment: That's a curious choice to enforce Windows-style line breaks over Unix-style. I wonder what the history behind that is

Answer (score 7):

Replace `\n` (and `\r\n`) by `%0D%0A` as specified by [RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) (in [section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-5)) updating the [`mailto` URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) as of October 2010 (replacing [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368)).

> [...] line breaks    in the body of a message MUST be encoded with `"%0D%0A"`.
> Implementations MAY add a final line break to the body of a message
> even if there is no trailing `"%0D%0A"` in the body [...]

This is the example from the RFC (in [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-6.1))

```
<mailto:infobot@example.com?body=send%20current-issue%0D%0Asend%20index>
```

The above mail body corresponds to:

```
send current-issue
send index
```