# How to make line break work in inbox by gmail using mailto?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to open mailto link in new tab which will automatically compose mail with dynamic data. It's work completely fine with other mail client except "Inbox by Gmail". Could you please help me with this.

```
mailto:x@y.com?body=FirstLine \r\n Second Line \r\n Third Line
```

Comment: Where do you want to post the body? in reply or compose?

Comment: I want to post body in compose

Comment: Are you trying this for Gmail on Web Browser?

Comment: Yes,
My whole message body converted to single line :FirstLine Second Line Third Line

https://inbox.google.com/

Comment: What I am asking is - Do you want to open Gmail on web browser and then open compose with those text? or do you want desktop based mail application to open a new message with these texts?

Comment: I want to open Inbox by Gmail on web browser and then open compose with those text

Comment: Could you please check below screenshot?

http://screencast.com/t/qjXu2DwQy0Y

Comment: Thats not possible.! It can only be done if you use any JavaScript API provided by Gmail. And I believe that is not there. Yes, but I guess this should work fine with normal desktop based application.

Comment: Okay, Any other solution for do this?

Comment: NO Solutions!! sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your UrlEncode method really translates newlines into "%0a". Here's an example of a 2-line email body:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&ui=2&tf=0&fs=1&to=WHOEVER%40COMPANY.COM&su=SUBJECTHERE&body=LINE1%0aLINE2

Comment: I am using "Inbox by gmail" that is https://inbox.google.com/

 Could you please check below screenshot?
http://screencast.com/t/qjXu2DwQy0Y

Comment: What happens when you use `mailto:x@y.com?body=LINE1%0aLINE2` ?

Comment: Same result as mentioned in above screenshot

Comment: Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this,

[Insert a line break in mailto body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765834/insert-a-line-break-in-mailto-body)

I had tried this and it is working, I think it is work for you.