# How to fix not showing line break in body while using mailto?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, email

My code:

```
<a href="mailto:anything@any.com?subject=This%20is%20Subject&body=Hello%0D%0A%0D%0Aworld..">
   click here to mail me
</a>
```

Expected output:

[image]

What i am getting as output now:

[image]

I tried using `%0D%0A` but it doesn't work. Also i tried few java script methods from [here](https://blog.deepbluesky.com/news/-/adding-line-breaks-to-mailto-links-27/) But those don't seems to work.

The app i used to check mailto: output is default Gmail App from my android device.

**EDIT [SOLUTION]**

Just using `<br>` tag works fine with third party applications like gmail for android.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 09 Sep 2020**
This has been changed again in a recent Gmail release - e.g. version `2020.08.09.327326543.Release` - `\r\n` for line breaks when using `mailto:` now works again and `<br>` does not.

I can only assume it was a regression bug rather than an intentional change in the Gmail app which has now been fixed.

**Original answer:**

I've seen an issue arise recently in my Android apps which have been using encoded `\r\n` for line breaks when using `mailto:` to open Gmail as the default email client.
While this previously worked fine, now the line break is appearing as a space.

Upon doing some testing, it appears that the behaviour of the Gmail app has changed in a recent update.

I created a [test page](https://dpa99c.github.io/test/mailto.html) which contains two links, one using encoded `\r\n` and one using `<br>` for a line break in the body:

```
mailto:anything@any.com?body=Hello%0D%0Aworld
mailto:anything@any.com?body=Hello<br>world
```

In an Android Emulator running Android 10/API 29 with Gmail app version of `2019.05.12.250526289.release`:

[image: pixel3-gmail]

The `\r\n` link works correctly:

[image: ![pixel3-rn]

But the `<br>` link does not:

[image: ![pixel3-br]

In an Android Emulator running Android 11 Beta/API 30 with Gmail app version of `2020.04.29.309137422.release`:

[image: pixel3a-gmail]

The `<br>` link works correctly:

[image: pixel3a-br]

But the `\r\n` link does not:

[image: pixel3a-rn]

Comment: Yep same for me

Answer (score 3):

%0D%0A are the carry return and line feed characters, use %20 for space as you do in the subject:

```
<a href="mailto:anything@any.com?subject=This%20is%20Subject&body=Hello%20world..">
   click here to mail me
</a>
```

And if you want a line break use `%0D%0A` as in:

```
<a href="mailto:anything@any.com?subject=This%20is%20Subject&body=Hello%0D%0Aworld..">
   click here to mail me
</a>
```

You can check what this values mean in a [ascii table](https://www.ascii-code.com/) if you check the hexadecimal value you see what A, D, E and 20 are equal to.

Comment: i need a line break like u said exactly in first line, i need return.. Not space. I know %20 used for space and found %0D%0A used for line break. But, when am using it, it doesn't work. Kindly go through my question or expexted output or atleast my title itself says i need line break. 

Comment: Kindly check out my post last quotes, i was trying it in gmail app Android. Is that u too tried with the same and works ? i click on website href mailto: it redirect to gmail app on mobile and doesn't give line break as i shown in expected output its a gmail app of android. (which most of the users used to mail me from my site) and i think u checked in pc and yes works for me to in pc browsers.

Comment: Yo are right, it was quicker to test on pc. Only in gmail in android fails. I've found a couple of posts asking for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276780/how-to-make-line-break-work-in-inbox-by-gmail-using-mailto and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065386/is-it-possible-to-add-a-new-line-in-mailto-url with the same problem and without any answer, `%0D%0A` should be the way but this seems to be a gmail bug in Android as this works on iOS gmail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing these post links  it works. I saw a comment in those posts says simply use `<br>` works with third party apps like gmail. I tried and works.

Comment: I'm glad you could solve your problem. You could add your own answer to your question and after a couple of days you will be able to mark it as correct, it might help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `<br>` tag, works fine with third party applications like gmail for android.

**Fixed code,**

```
<a href="mailto:anything@any.com?subject=This%20is%20Subject&body=Hello<br><br>world..">
   click here to mail me
</a>
```