# mailto link with mail body not working

Tags: java, email, hyperlink

I am passing the complete `href` encoded value from the back end. and sending a mail to user. In the mail body we have an anchor link; by clicking on it the mail body should open with predefined subject and body. The mail is getting triggered but the when I click on the anchor link, the mail is not opening.

Java code:

```
    String rejectBody = "mailto:?subject=Rejected - PP - Claim record #20170085&body=Dear <User name>,\r\n" + 
            "Your PP –Claim Record #20170085 request has been Rejected.\r\n" + 
            "This is an automated email. Please do not reply.";
    String approvedBody = "mailto:?subject=Approved - PP - Claim record #20170085&body=Dear <User name>,\r\n" + 
            "Your PP –Claim Record #20170085 request has been Approved.\r\n" + 
            "This is an automated email. Please do not reply.";
    try {
        String encoderejectBody=URLEncoder.encode( rejectBody, "UTF-8" );
        String encodeApprovedBody=URLEncoder.encode( approvedBody, "UTF-8" );
        claimDetails.setApprovedBody(encodeApprovedBody);
        claimDetails.setRejectBody(encoderejectBody);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Velocity vm file:

```
  <div>
     <table align="center"  cellspacing="40">
        <th  style="background-color: #4CAF50;border-color: #4CAF50;border: 2px solid #4CAF50;padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;text-align: center;border-radius:5px;">
           <a style="display: block;color: #ffffff;font-size: 15px;text-decoration: none;" href=${email.rejectBody}>
           Reject
           </a>
        </th>
        <th style="background-color: #4CAF50;border-color: #4CAF50;border: 2px solid #4CAF50;padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;text-align: center;border-radius:5px;">
           <a style="display: block;color: #ffffff;font-size: 15px;text-decoration: none;" href=${email.approvedBody}>
           Approve
           </a>
        </th>
        </table>
  </div>
```

Ouptut:

[image]

But clicking on link the maito functionality is not working.
Please help me.

Comment: I doubt you can insert newlines like that. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765834/insert-a-line-break-in-mailto-body) thread.

Comment: `href="${email.approvedBody}"`?

Comment: Could you show us the encoded mailto links that are applied to the `a`s?

Comment: I have resolved it.The problem is with encoding. It worked fine. thanks for the all your help