# How to create an email body from static input text?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a text input form on a static page and convert that to an email body using the mailto option. For example, the following with take the input from the text box

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and in the email body will display as

```
Hello ABC,

The details are:

First Name: Mickey
Last Name: Mouse

Thanks,
XYZ
```

Comment: And? What have you tried?

Comment: As of now, I am only able to get the placeholder values into the email and not free text.

Comment: And the code that you used to do that is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the time to round up a few answers for you. I hope that you take the time to read through each of the links provided.

First you want to get your [form data as an object](https://code.lengstorf.com/get-form-values-as-json/):

```
const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {  
  data[element.name] = element.value;
  return data;
}, {});
```

I've used [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to set defaults for some constants to use in the mailto:

```
const { 
  recipientName = "ABC", recipientAddress = "abc@123.yes",
  subject = "Some mailz for youz", senderName = "XYZ",
  firstname = "first", lastname = "last"
} = formToJSON(document.querySelectorAll("form input:not([type='submit'])"))
```

We also need some [linebreaks in our email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765834/insert-a-line-break-in-mailto-body):

```
const lineBreak = "%0D%0A"
```

And finally [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct our [href for mailto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto):

```
const mailTo = `mailto:${recipientAddress}?subject=${subject}&body=Hello ABC,${lineBreak}
I am your father.${lineBreak}${lineBreak}
The details are:${lineBreak}${lineBreak}
First Name: ${firstname}${lineBreak}
Last Name: ${lastname}${lineBreak}${lineBreak}
Thanks,${lineBreak}
${senderName}`
```

Here's the snippet so you can see it all working together:

```js
const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {  
  data[element.name] = element.value;
  return data;
}, {});

const { 
  recipientName = "ABC", recipientAddress = "abc@123.yes",
  subject = "Some mailz for youz", senderName = "XYZ",
  firstname = "first", lastname = "last"
} = formToJSON(document.querySelectorAll("form input:not([type='submit'])"))

const lineBreak = "%0D%0A"

const mailTo = `mailto:${recipientAddress}?subject=${subject}&body=Hello ABC,${lineBreak}
I am your father.${lineBreak}${lineBreak}
The details are:${lineBreak}${lineBreak}
First Name: ${firstname}${lineBreak}
Last Name: ${lastname}${lineBreak}${lineBreak}
Thanks,${lineBreak}
${senderName}`

const link = document.createElement("a")
link.textContent = "Send some mailz yaaaal"
link.href = mailTo
document.body.appendChild(link)
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```