# Line break doesn't show correctly when used in a mailto link

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, html-email

*ts*

```
 send(): void {
    const body: string = `First Name: ${this.form.value.firstName}` + '\n' + `Last Name:${this.form.value.lastName}`;
    console.log('body', body);
    const url: string = `mailto:me@y.com?Subject=Sell My House&body=${body}`;
    window.open(url);
  }
```

Console.log shows correctly:

```
body First Name: sampath
Last Name:lokuge
```

But why email client doesn't show it correctly

[image]

Comment: Try \n\r instead of just \n. Explanation is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47af2197-26b4-4b9e-90e8-bfa9d5cd05b4/what-is-the-deference-between-r-n-and-rn-)

Comment: @barinbritva No difference. Same result. :(

Comment: Another thing may be here. Possible it's important  to specify content type header for Windows Mail client. But, it's just my guess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a line break in mailto body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765834/insert-a-line-break-in-mailto-body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's feedback**

I have done it like so: i.e. `%0D%0A`

```
const body: string = `First Name: ${this.form.value.firstName}` + '%0D%0A' + `Last Name: ${this.form.value.lastName}`
```

**Original**

That is normal behavior for HTML and whitespace. All whitespace is condensed into one, and considered a single space.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Whitespace

The css white-space property can fix that `white-space: pre-line` is likely what you want, but there are other options
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Now, weather or not your email clients will respect that css `white-space` property you'll need to test.  Otherwise you may want to add HTML line breaks `<br>` or wrap each line in a `<div>` or `<p>`

Comment: No. I need to do this is using `Typescript/Javascript`. i..e No `CSS`

Comment: Just realized you are creating a mailto link and clicking that for the user, so this isn't quite answering the question.

Comment: You can see that I need to add lot of Typescript things on that page.

Comment: I've commented on your original question again, your problem is specific to using `mailto` links to open an email, not really html emails themselves.